# Two adjacent DIVs with dynamic content. One wrap content, other scroll overflow

Tags: html, css, dynamic, height

I have to show 2 adjacent boxes, both have a dynamic content (rendered using angular). The `Container` must have the height of `Box1`. `Box2`s heigth may vary due to the dynamicity and it should not be higher as `Box1`. If higher a scroll should be shown.

I started with the following code using tables:

```
<table id="Container">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" id="Box1">
            <dynamic rendered html code/>
        <td>
        <td>&nbsp;<td>
        <td valign="top" style="position: relative; id="Box2">
            <div style="position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; overflow-x: hidden">
                <dynamic rendered html code/>
            </div>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately it does not work in IE, since (as I'v read on the web) *position* is not defined for tables (not HTML standard);

So I decided to switch to divs:

```
<div id="Container">
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top" id="Box1">
        <dynamic rendered html code/>
    <div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">&nbsp;<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top" id="Box2">
        <dynamic rendered html code/>
    <div>
</div>
```

`Box1` should always wrap its content. `Box2` should not be heigher than `Box1`, IF then scroll overflow.
Is it possible in CSS? No JQuery and no Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `#Box2`'s height equal to `#Box1`'s height.

There is no way to align there height within the same parent. Therefore, I suggest you to wrap `#Box2` with `#Box1` like below.

```
<div id="Box1">
    <div id="Box2">
    </div>
</div>
```

And that you can set `max-height: 100%;` to `#Box2` so that the maximum height of `#Box2` will not be larger than `#Box1`.

Adding `overflow-x: auto;` to `#Box2` can show scrollbar automatically when text overflow.

https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/LMVoZd

Comment: Great! But can we have dynamic widths ?

Comment: @Emaborsa you can set percentage `width` to `#Box1` respect to its parent `#Container` or even set `width` to 100% and let `#Container` do the job. Afterwards, you can set percentage `width` to `#Box2` respect to `#Box1`

I have updated the codepen.

Comment: Not really. I have other code in the page, which can be larger than the `Container`. Tale a look to this https://codepen.io/Emaborsa/pen/BvNXNr

Comment: @Emaborsa Sorry I don't understand your situation. 

`#Container` can be an individual block anyway. You can set it own `width`, set `width` to parent, or even use `flex`.